# Passing mutable dictionary as default argument in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to implement the below code to reinitialize a new object. But it isn't happening

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, arg):
        super(A, self).__init__()
        self.arg = arg

    def method(self):
        self.arg[1] += 1
        print(self.arg)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a1 = A({1: 1, 2:2, 3:3})
    a1.method()
    a2 = A(a1.arg)
    a1.method()
    a3 = A(a1.arg)
    a1.method()


Expected Output: {1: 2, 2:2, 3:3}
                 {1: 2, 2:2, 3:3}
                 {1: 2, 2:2, 3:3}
                   
Code Output: {1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 3}
             {1: 3, 2: 2, 3: 3}
             {1: 4, 2: 2, 3: 3}
```

I found some links online where they explain about Python Mutable defaults. But couldn't find a solution to this problem.

Comment: After `a1.method()` you have no longer `{1: 1, 2:2, 3:3}` anywhere so you just can't if you use only one `arg`

Comment: So how can we achieve this behaviour?

Comment: You really want to reuse `a1.arg` ? Your usecase it not well defined or jsut seems to be a test, so if you want a good solution, provide a good usecase ;)

Comment: Yes, this is not the actual usual case. Actually, I have a class Graph whose instance variable is a dictionary(adjacency list). I am computing the min cuts in this dictionary, so I am modifying the instances(in this case removing the dictionary keys). After finding the minimum cut, I have to run this process again. So I am creating another graph object and making use of the original graph object to do the min cut operation

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the line

```py
self.arg = arg
```

to

```py
self.arg = arg.copy()
```

This way, each `A` object gets its own copy of the dictionary; they don't all have to share.

Comment: Can this be achieved without copy()

Answer (score 0):

you're only using `method()` on your `a1` so it's normal that it keeps updating `self.arg[1]` at each calls.

---

Maybe you would'd like to do this :

```
a1 = A({1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3})
a1.method()
a2 = A(a1.arg)
a2.method()
a3 = A(a1.arg)
a3.method()

outout : 
{1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 3}
{1: 3, 2: 2, 3: 3}
{1: 4, 2: 2, 3: 3}
```

but it does't work because the objects are "sharing" the same array. see [Mutable vs Immutable Objects](https://towardsdatascience.com/https-towardsdatascience-com-python-basics-mutable-vs-immutable-objects-829a0cb1530a)

---

So you can use `.copy` But even this will fail. Because when you're creating `a2` and `a3`, you're passing `{1: 2, 2:2, 3:3}` in the argument because the initial arg have changed due to the use of `method()` on `a1`

```
a1 = A({1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3})
a1.method()
a2 = A(a1.arg.copy())
a2.method()
a3 = A(a1.arg.copy())
a3.method()

outout : 
{1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 3}
{1: 3, 2: 2, 3: 3}
{1: 3, 2: 2, 3: 3}
```